Oracle_Database_19C: dba_datapump_jobs
We're having an Oracle database 19c, in that few dumps was there. Regarding this we've kept the scheduled backup jobs for keep maintain the dump backups. But in these 2 dumps getting the error as below mentioned and remaining all getting well. Can you please advise on this, how can resolve this for avoid the further issues on this.

ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -942
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in KUPM$MCP.SET_LONGOPS
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

